Initial default form value for input v-model doesn't work vue
I have a form where I display a few fields. I want to have a default value for those fields but when I edit them the updated value to be saved. I also use these fields in a child component where I render them.
data () {
return {
  form: new Form({
    email_subject: 'Default Value',
    brand_name: '',
    header_text: 'Header text'
  })
}

}
<div>
   <label class="form-control-label">
     {{ $t('labels.email_subject') }}
   </label>

   <span v-if="!isEditable" class="font-weight-400 margin-left-5">{{ form.email_subject }}</span>

   <div class="from-group">
       <v-text-field
        v-if="isEditable"
        v-model="form.email_subject"
        name="email_subject"
        class-name="form-control text-field"
        type="text"
       />

        <div v-if="form.hasError('email_subject')" class="form-control-error-list">
          <ul>
             <li v-for="error in form.collectError('email_subject')" :key="error">{{ error }}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

and in the child component:
<div class="text-left mt-3 pl-1 ">
  {{ subject }}
</div>

props: {
subject: {
  type: String,
  required: true
},

<email-phone
 :subject="form.email_subject"
 :brand="form.brand_name"
 :header="form.header_text"
/>

The issue is the Default Value or Header text are not initially displayed if the field is empty and cannot understand why. What am I doing wrong?

Where does new Form() come from?  Please tag or mention in your question any relevant third party libraries.  it's not a standard JS interface, so it's unknown what this contructor is returning.  Based on your issue, it seems as though email_subject, brand_name, etc. are not root properties.  You may want to console.log what form is after initialization and confirm the data within.

Also, what is Vue version? You can't expect classes to be reactive in Vue 2 at all
